# How to test condition rendered elements with react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I'm trying to cover my functionality with test, i have the image input:

```
<input
    data-testid="fileuploadtestid"
    type="file"
    accept="image/*"
    capture="camera"
    onChange={uploadImage}
/>
```

On change method checks if file provided and creates the link;

```
const uploadImage = (e) => {
    const { files } = e.target;

    if (files?.length) {
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);

      setImageUrl(url);
    } else {
      setImageUrl("");
    }
  };
```

Based on `imageUrl` value image renders conditionally:

```
{imageUrl && (
    <img
      data-testid="prevtestid"
      className="preview_img"
      src={imageUrl}
      alt={imageUrl}
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
      ref={imageRef}
     />
  )}
```

And i want to check if it renders correctly using `react testing library` to get the image element I use `data-testid="prevtestid"`:

```
test("renders learn react link", async () => {
  const { container, rerender } = render(<Home />);
  global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
  const file = new File(["(⌐□_□)"], "pug.png", { type: "image/png" });

  const input = screen.getByTestId("fileuploadtestid");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { files: [file] } });

  rerender(<Home />);
expect(screen.getByTestId("prevtestid")).toBeInTheDocument();
}
);
```

I attached the latest version what have i tried to implement, i tried to use `waitFor`, `rerender`, `render` in various ways but i'm getting the same error all time:
`Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="prevtestid"]`.

Please tell me how can i test it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock that you are creating is not really returning anything. You should return a url so that the components get's an `imageUrl` and is then able to show the `<img />` element.

```
global.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('https://www.samplerandomdomain.com/images/123.jpg');
```